# Angular filter search with similar and not exact words

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The filter only finds text that matches exactly but not similar. E.g. if one of the entries was "John Dwayne Smith", user has to type those words in exact order for them to be searched by the filter, but how to make the search work in a way that the "Hello there, world!" gets displayed even when a person types a combination of those words, as in, "John Smith"?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="userSearch">

   <div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:userSearch">
     <div>
       {{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}
     </div>
   </div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.users = [

    {firstname: 'john', lastname: 'dwayne smith'},
    {firstname: 'jane', lastname: 'dwayne due'},
    {firstname: 'bob', lastname: 'dwayne rand'}

  ];

});
```

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/siyuzariha/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: try this  .. | filter:{firstname:userSearch}:true

Comment: see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xie_qianyue/jegfk1tw/), the combination work.

Comment: filter:{firstname:userSearch}:true doesnt work

Comment: @Qianyue, in that fiddle, if you type John Smith, the search doesn't find the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter).  It provides a [fuzzy filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#fuzzy).

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="search book" />
<li ng-repeat="book in books | fuzzy: search">
  {{ book.title }}
</li>
<!--case sensitive-->
<li ng-repeat="book in books | fuzzy: search: true">
  {{ book.title }}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use angular filter, | filter works as '**like**' but if you add :true in the end, then it works as '**equal**'

Comment: I am not using :true, so it should work as I want it to, if what you say is true, am I right?

Comment: Try update you ng-repeat as: ng-repeat="user in users | filter:userSearch:true

Comment: Also you can try this: ng-repeat="user in users | filter:userSearch:strict"